# What are the parameters for AuthorizeRequest event?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

What are the parameters for the `System.Web.HttpApplication.AuthorizeRequest` event?

In general how do I discover the parameters required of an event, given the DLL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check event delegate type.

From [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.authorizerequest(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1):

> public event EventHandler AuthorizeRequest

So delegate for `AuthorizeRequest` is `EventHandler`.

From [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.eventhandler%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> public delegate void EventHandler(    Object sender,  EventArgs e )

`AuthorizeRequest` parameters :

- Object sender
- EventArgs e